# Check the current class in "real time" in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do the following thing...
I have a menu that changes when I start to scroll the page:

```
        $(window).scroll(function(){
                if( $(window).scrollTop() > 1 ) {
                        $('nav').addClass( "smaller" );
                        $('nav').removeClass( "bigger" );
                        $('nav').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0 });
                } else {
                        $('nav').removeClass( "smaller" );
                        $('nav').addClass( "bigger" );
                        $('nav').css('top', '32px');
                }
        });
```

Then I need a script that checks the current class and perform another action. For example:

```
if ($('nav').hasClass('bigger') ) {
    var someVar = -132;
} else {
    var someVar = -153;
};
```

Unfortunately, the script behaves as if the class is not changed. Still sees the first state.

What can you do about it? How to check class in "real time"?

Answer (score 0):

You really can't. That would require constant sniffing and would be resource-intensive. The right approach is to use a callback on the original (scroll) function:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1) {
        $('nav').addClass("smaller");
        $('nav').removeClass("bigger");
        $('nav').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': 0,
            'left': 0
        });

        someOtherFunction();
    } ...
});
```

Also, you can simplify your code by chaining:

```
$('nav').addClass("smaller").removeClass("bigger").css({
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your concept is similar to the basis of DOM mutation events. However, this feature is not widely implemented across browsers for one reason — it is extremely resource intensive to keep track of every single DOM node. And this is precisely why DOM mutation events have been [officially deprecated](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2011JulSep/0779.html).

Instead of thinking about evaluating the class conditionals at every single instance (frame per second, perhaps?), you can instead decide what to do when the class is added or removed, all built into the scroll event of the window object. Also remember that **you can chain jQuery methods**:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > 1 ) {
        $('nav').addClass( "smaller" ).removeClass( "bigger" ).css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0 });
        var someVar = -153;
    } else {
        $('nav').removeClass( "smaller" ).addClass( "bigger" ).css('top', '32px');
        var someVar = -132;
    }
});
```

If you are worried about performance issue due to constant, excessive firing of the scroll event during user interaction, you might want to look into [throttling it](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/).